# Horizontal Context Menu UWP

Tags: uwp, contextmenu

I want to create a horizontally arranged context menu like this image in my UWP app. How can I do that?

[image: Click to see the image]

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could edit default `CommandBar` style to approach. the default more button of `CommandBar` is horizontal, we need to rotate it 90°, and add insert the separator into `CommandBar`. And I have make complete style [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TestPoline/blob/master/TestPoline/MainPage.xaml#L524), you could use it directly.

```
<CommandBar        
   Width="250"
    DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
    IsOpen="False"
    IsSticky="True"
    >
    <AppBarButton FontWeight="Bold" Label="Add" />
    <AppBarButton FontWeight="Bold" Label="Edit" />
    <AppBarButton FontWeight="Bold" Label="Share" />
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Settings">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                <KeyboardAccelerator Key="I" Modifiers="Control" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Nico Zhu. Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to show the context menu at different position (on mouse click/touch position). In MenuFlyout, there is a function, "ShowAt" which can serve my purpose. But Command bar doesn't have it. So how can I make MenuFlyout horizontal?

Comment: MenuFlyout  does not support horizontal, you could try to use Flyout to replace and custom flyout content with horizontal layout usercontrol.